# Estimate $|f(x)| \le \frac C{|x|^3}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $$f(x) = \frac{\sin x}x+\frac{\sin(x-1)}{2(x-1)}+\frac{\sin(x+1)}{2(x+1)}.$$
>   Find the common denominator and use common trigonometric identities to establish that
>   $$|f(x)| \le \frac C{|x^3|}$$
>   for large values of $x$. Note that $C$ is a positive constant.

Following these instructions, I find that
$$|f(x)| = \left|\frac{(x^2-1)\sin x + x^2 \sin x \cos 1 - x \cos x \sin 1}{x^3-x} \right|$$
but I don't think this is quite right because I have $x$ terms in the numerator.

Comment: Yes, I already stated this in the question..

Comment: It can't be true: for $x$ with $\sin{x}=1$, the numerator grows like $x^2$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha disagrees with the $O(1/x^3)$ and finds it just $O(1/x)$, consistently with your simplification.  Wolfram Alpha also agrees with your simplification.

Comment: Are you sure it is $\frac{C} {|x|^3}$ not  $\frac{C} {|x|}$?

Comment: Maybe my homework assignment has a typo.

Answer (score 1):

$$|f(x)| = \left|\frac{(x^2)\sin x-\sin x + x^2 \sin x \cos 1 - x \cos x \sin 1}{x^3-x} \right|$$
$$= \left|\frac{\sin x(\cos x + 1)-\frac{\sin x}{x^2}  - \frac{\cos x \sin 1}{x}}{x-\frac{1}{x}} \right|$$
Now notice that the trig functions in front are bounded between $0$ and $2$, notice that this approaches $|\frac{C}{x}|$ for large $x$. More formally,
$$f(x) \in O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
As you mention in the comments, I assume your assignment has a typo.